# Wordpress навигационное меню

Tags: php, css, wordpress

столкнулся с такой проблемой, что у меня неправильно отображается мое меню. Скорей всего из-за стилей. Дело в том, что мой контейнер записан в таком ввиде.

```
.navbar > .container {
z-index: 999;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
left: 0;
height: 90px;
width: 100%;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: center;
```

Но если я выбираю контейнер для wp_nav_menu, то он берет либо стиль из .container либо из .navbar . Селектор ">" игнорирует напрочь.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Меню сверху отображается некорректно, а должно выглядеть то как показано под этим меню.

Answer (score 0):

```css
column-count: 1;
-moz-column-count: 1;
-webkit-column-count: 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.navbar a {
    display: inline;
}
```